# Counting items open on each Sunday (or any day of week)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query I'd like to set up which would basically list all Sundays in column 1, then in column 2 for each date, it would count all of the items that were 'open' on that Sunday (the column 1 date, could actually be an day of the week, the important thing is to get a weekly snapshot of open items). e.g.

```
Date               open items
------------       ---------------
2013-10-13         1650
2013-10-06         1554
2013-09-29         1788
(cont down)
```

My database records the openDate and closedDate of each item.  So column 2 would need something like: Count the total items that have an open date <= the column 1 date AND have either NULL in the closed date (item still open) or closedDate >= the column 1 date.

I hope you can help.  I think this query is past the limit of my current limited SQL powers.

Many thanks
Robo-ted

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: You think it's above your skills? So what did you try so far? ;-)

Comment: How many Sundays do you want to see? The last month? The last year?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can do the following

```
create procedure dbo.DoSummary(@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime, @dow int)
as 
set DateFIRST @dow;

with cte (date) as (
    select case
            when datepart(dw, @startdate) = 1 then @startdate
            else dateadd(d,8-datepart(dw, @startdate), @startdate)
            end as date
    union all
    select dateadd(d,7, date)
    from cte where dateadd(d,7,date) < @enddate
)
select 
    cte.date, count(items.opened) as [Open]
from 
    cte left outer join items on cte.date >= items.opened and cte.date < coalesce(items.closed, dateadd(d,1,cte.date))
    group by cte.date
```

Then you just execute

```
dbo.DoSummary '2001-01-01','2001-07-01', 7
```

To execute.

The last parameter `@dow` controls which day of the week to use, 7 is Sunday

*UPDATE* As OP doesn't have access to create a stored procedure you can simply use the function body as as your raw Sql.  I'll give an example using ADO from c#.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
   using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
     cmd.CommandText = "set DateFIRST @dow; " +
                       "with cte (date) as ( " +
                       "select case " +
                       "when datepart(dw, @startdate) = 1 then @startdate "+
                       "else dateadd(d,8-datepart(dw, @startdate), @startdate) " +
                       "end as date " +
                       "union all " +
                       "select dateadd(d,7, date) " +
                       "from cte where dateadd(d,7,date) < @enddate " +
                       ") " +
                       "select cte.date, count(items.opened) as [Open] " +
                       "from cte " +
                       "left outer join items " +
                       "on cte.date >= items.opened " +
                       "and cte.date < coalesce(items.closed, dateadd(d,1,cte.date)) "+
                       "group by cte.date ";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", new DateTime(2001,01,01));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", new DateTime(2001,04,01));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dow", 7);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      while (reader.Read()) {
         // do somthing with data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bob thanks for the code.  Unfortunately, I don't have 'write' privileges to the database and so I am unable to set up any procedures myself.  I could ask the IT dept to do this but it wouldn't be a great priority of theirs.  Do you know if there is a single query that would deal with this?  Something I can use as a query to an ADO recordset?  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2878967 Updated answer with c# ADO example.  You can just use the function body and pass the parameters in as ado parameters to the query